# Nginx Not finding static files

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to serve some static files (images) on nginx and I'm always getting 404.

This is the url I'm testing:

> /uploads/test.png

I have the folder with the images in:

> /root/project/server/uploads

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    
    root /var/www/html;


    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires 12h;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
    
    location /uploads  {
        alias /root/trendcircle/server/uploads;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /api { 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Origin, x-access-token';

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;       
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081; 
    }
}
```

Can some one help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try: `root /root/project/server;`

Comment: The path in `location /uploads` does not match the location where your image is actually stored. Try changing that

Comment: @RichardSmith it still doesn't work

Comment: @luíssaraiva Check the nginx error log to see where nginx tries to find the requested file.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks you I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The folder didn't have the same user as the user running nginx. If it by executing this command:

> chmod o+x /root